# Ubuntu mate: Couldn't use screenshot keyboard shortcut as expected

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

In my newly installed Ubuntu Mate, I tried setting the keyboard shortcut exactly in the way shown in this article
https://medium.com/@dorukdestan/ubuntu-shortcut-for-partial-screenshot-to-clipboard-3a4018e8d3dd

However, when I save the keyboard shortcut and press the keys, it doesn't work the first time, I have to press it 8-9 times or just hold shift+ctrl+alt+s for a while for it to activate the screenshot UI.
I'm not sure what might be causing this. Please let me know

Comment: For more productive result ask this question also on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .